# How to loop the contents of mapbox in an array using angular2 to use inside *ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mapbox-gl-js

i have written the function to give markers with respect to coordinates given in typescript, but i want to put those in an array and loop it. so that it can be used in html with *ngFor can anyone help me to sort this issue.

TS:

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoicmFrc2hpdGhhMTkiLCJhIjoiY2pjcHl1YW5wMjR5czJ6bzdqdjZrbDRzeSJ9.OOqu6zVyNsXavzCsYoBdPA';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'maps',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
      center: [12.568337,55.676098],
      zoom: 9
});

  map.on('load', function () {
    map.addLayer({
      "id": "points",
      "type": "circle",
      "paint":{
        "circle-radius":10,
        "circle-color":'rgba(55,148,179,1)'    
      },
      "source": {
        "type": "geojson",
        "data": {
          "type": "FeatureCollection",
          "features": [
            {
              "type": "Feature",
              "properties": {},
              "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [12.568337,55.676098]
              }
            },
            {
              "type": "Feature",
              "properties": {},
              "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [13.077576,55.670667]
              }
            },
            {
              "type": "Feature",
              "properties": {},
              "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [12.35112,55.816349]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id='maps' style="height:440px"></div>
```

Comment: which array you want to loop?

Comment: the coordinates array

Comment: your map.addLayer declaration is wrong. Make tht as array

Answer (score 0):

You need nested **`ngFor`** as below

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let cordinates of source.data.features" > 
 <div *ngFor="let cordiante of cordinates.geometry.coordinates" [latitude]="m[0]" [longitude]="m[1]" ></div>
</ng-container>
```

and assign

```
this.source = yourArray;
```

Comment: ya i need like this kind in html.. but in ts i must write the function in an array

Comment: Replace the same code inside .ts using let(let cordinates of source.data.features)

Comment: ya in .ts file only i had written the above function, and i have used only import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';

Comment: I got this error, after placing html
Can't bind to 'latitude' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("inates of source.data.features" > 
 <div *ngFor="let cordiante of cordinates.geometry.coordinates" [ERROR ->][latitude]="m[0]" [longitude]="m[1]" id="maps" style="height:440px"></div>
</ng-container>

Comment: you need to replace with map

Comment: should i put the html as it is given by you? and how about the array in this.source?

Answer (score 0):

```
You will get array now. Loop tht now in html using *ngFor

  map.addLayer = [{
  "id": "points",
  "type": "circle",
  "paint":{
    "circle-radius":10,
    "circle-color":'rgba(55,148,179,1)'    
  },
  "source": {
    "type": "geojson",
    "data": {
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {},
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [12.568337,55.676098]
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {},
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [13.077576,55.670667]
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {},
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [12.35112,55.816349]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
}];
```